# ЗаговОр и  зАговор

Tags: фонетика

Скажите, пожалуйста, если речь идет не о заговоре против правительства, а о фольклорных магических заговорах, ударение в слове все равно "зАговор" или все-таки "заговОр"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, нормативно зАговор во всех значениях.

На мой взгляд, "заговОр" можно было бы признать возможным в отвлеченном значении "действие по глаголу заговаривать" (т.к. есть прилагательное заговОрный, которое почему-то не признаёт Кузнецов), но такого значения словарями не фиксируется.